# clone git repository to an FTP server

Tags: git, ftp, repository, heroku, clone

I've done quite a bit of searching on Stackoverflow and on various websites and can't seem to find a quick answer on how to clone a git repository from my local machine to an FTP server.

I'm working with Ubuntu 10.04 LTS. Also my webapp is being run on Heroku.

Comment: You should clone the repo locally and then push the clone to the FTP server.

Answer (score 1):

You don't clone a repository *to* a remote place, but *from* a remote place *to your system*.

If you want your repository on a FTP server, upload it by hand using an FTP client, and push your future commits by referring its FTP url.

On course, if you have SSH access to your server, you can also log in it, and clone from there.

Answer (score 0):

Important note:

don't forget to do a
`git update-server-info`
before uploading the repository to your ftp server

and maybe adding it to a `post-update` script so that your `info/refs` file is current !